# How to extract relational data from a flat table using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access, etl

I have a single flat table containing a list of people which records their participation in different groups and their activities over time. The table contains following columns:
- name (first/last)
- e-mail
- secondary e-mail
- group
- event date 
+ some other data in a series of columns, relevant to a specific event (meeting, workshop).

I want to extract distinct people from that into a separate table, so that further down the road it could be used for their profiles giving them a list of what they attended and relevant info. In other words, I would like to have a list of people (profiles) and then link that to a list of groups they are in and then a list of events per group they participated in.

Obviously, same people appear a number of times:

```
| Full name  | email                | secondary email     | group | date       |
| John Smith | jsmith@someplace.com |                     | AcOP  | 2010-02-12 |
| John Smith | jsmith@gmail.com     | jsmith@somplace.com | AcOP  | 2010-03-14 |
| John Smith | jsmith@gmail.com     |                     | CbDP  | 2010-03-18 |
| John Smith | jsmith@someplace.com |                     | BDz   | 2010-04-02 |
```

Of course, I would like to roll it into one record for John Smith with both e-mails in the resulting People table. I can't rule out that there might be more records for same person with other e-mails than those two - I can live with that. To make it more complex ideally I would like to derive a list of groups, creating a Groups table (possibly with further details on the groups) and then a list of meetings/activities for each group. By linking that I would then have clean relational model.

Now, the question: is there a way to perform such a transformation of data in SQL? Or do I need to write a procedure (program) that would traverse the database and do it?

The database is in MySQL, though I can also use MS Access (it was given to me in that format).

Comment: And what results do you want?

Comment: - People table with just one record for John Smith, listing all his e-mails
- Groups table listing all groups
- Participation table linking (by some IDs) People to Group, with dates of each participation

Or I think at least that would be best.

Comment: Are you (incorrectly) assuming that `Full name` is a unique identifier for people?

Comment: If all the data is already in this one table, what benefit is there in trying to break it apart into multiple tables?

Comment: @Bohemian I assume e-mail to be my best ID for now, later I'll introduce People's IDs.

Comment: @Andrew - because I don't know how to efficiently use it in this form to get what I want. Plus it will be updated later from a system that has People as separate objects.

Comment: If full name is not the identifier and email is, why did you say *Of course, I would like to roll it into one record for John Smith with both e-mails*? You contradict yourself. Please clarify. Also please show desired result from your sample data.

Comment: @Bohemian I don't contradict myself, because record in row 2 of my example table clearly links both e-mail addresses as belonging to the same person, hence all four records (and possibly more) where he gave any of the two e-mails must belong to the same person.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool that does this automatically. You will have to write a couple queries (unless you want to write a DTS package or something proprietary). Here's a typical approach:

1. Write two select statements for the two tables you wish to create-- one for users and one for groups. You may need to use DISTINCT or GROUP BY to ensure you only get one row when the source table contains duplicates.
2. Run the two select statements and inspect them for problems. For example, it's possible some users show up with two different email addresses, or some users have the same name and were combined incorrectly. These will need to be cleaned up in order to proceed. There is great way to do this-- it's more or less a manual process requiring expert knowledge of the data.
3. Write CREATE TABLE scripts based on the two SELECT statements so that you can store the results somewhere.
4. Use INSERT FROM or SELECT INTO to populate the tables from your two SELECT statements.